# What are the benefits of code blocks inside a method?

Tags: java

I've seen a method, which contains several blocks:

```
public class SomeClass {
    public void someMethod() {
        {
            ...
        }
        {
            ...
        }
        {
            ...
        }       
    }
}
```

What are the benefits of such structure compared to the usual approach (put the code of each of the blocks into its own method and call them from `someMethod`) ?

What could be the reason the author of that source wrote it that way?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

They can be useful for organising local variables:

```
{
    List<String> someTemporaryThing = getTemporaryThing();
    processTemporaryThing1(someTemporaryThing);
    processTemporaryThing2(someTemporaryThing);
}

// other code that doesn't need to see someTemporaryThing
```

Of course, if you have more than a few lines in one of these it might be a good idea to make it a separate method.

I haven't found any other use for them.

Comment: `Of course, if you have more than a few lines in one of these ...` Well, if you're able to structure your method like that, then you should *always* consider moving these blocks in separate lines. Methods should be as short as possible and this will "generate" more (and hopefully meaningful) method names and this is a good thing.

Comment: @Tom IMO excessive use of methods makes code harder to follow. And they can be very hard to think of good names for (beyond e.g. `processTemporaryThing`)

Comment: +one for Tom. A new line is better if you want to separate local variables.

Comment: @immibis if they make the code harder to follow, then this code has other problems, too. Maybe too many methods in one class (which might cause problems with the *single responsibility principle*). And if the programmer has no better name than `processTemporaryThing`, then he should improve his skills in naming "things" anyway :D.

Answer (score 1):

This is legacy from C, where, originally, variables could be declared only at the start of a code block (i.e. right after a `{`).

In Java, it is only useful if, as you said already, you don't want to move the code in these blocks to separate methods, but want to keep their variables out of your method's scope. This could theoretically get some increase in performance compared to taking the stuff out to methods.

Comment: I'm curious, do you have some revelant source explaining this in more details ?

Comment: @Jean-FrançoisSavard: sorry, I don't. As I said in my answer, this is only a theoretical advantage, if we regard this technique as a form of manual inlining.